# I cannot get a separate layout for a certain action to work in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the life of me, I've tried every way to get a separate layout for my `show` action in my user model to generate.

I simply want all actions to render the `application` layout and the show action to render the `profile` layout.

So please, if anyone has a way (in rails 3) to do it, please inform me. I've been going at this for a while (I'm sure it's simple, it almost always is)..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the :layout option when rendering the show template:

```
render :layout => "profile"
```

Comment: that was my original approach, but now it's not recognizing any of my methods or values, for example it used to render `@user.first_name` just fine and when I use a new layout it says `undefined method 'first_name' -- any idea why?

Comment: I'm also getting `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".`

Comment: Could you post your controller code. Looks like somewhere render/redirect is called more than once. May be some filter is also trying to render the specific layout for the show action.

Answer (score 0):

it is quite easy

layout :choose_layout

def choose_layout

return "layout_a" if action_name=="show"
return "application"

end

Comment: I think this would be helpful for me but its hard to read. Where should I put this method?